# Why does Django CSRF verification fail?

Tags: django

So I have a register form in Django. However when I fill in the form and hit submit, the page remains loading. (I'm not sure if this is the right expression. icon in the tab title turns to a rotating circle.) The page was loading for quite a long time, so I clicked the submit button again, and I got the Forbidden message, saying CSRF token is not verified. This keeps on happening. 
However the thing is, when I access the admin page, the user account IS created. And log in works fine. 
 The only problem is when I hit submit button, it only keeps on loading, and when I hit the submit button again, I get error message saying CSRF token is not verified, but the account is created. What is wrong with it? I'll show you my code.

```
<form method="post" class="form-group">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row login-block">
        <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-4">
                        {{form.username|as_crispy_field}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-8">
                        {{form.email|as_crispy_field}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-5">
                        {{form.password1|as_crispy_field}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-5">
                        {{form.password2|as_crispy_field}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-left">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn menial-buttons">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def register(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            newUser =  authenticate(response, username=username, password=password)
            if newUser:
                login(response, newUser)
                return redirect('/inputuserinfo')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

        a = form.fields['username']
        b = form.fields['email']
        c = form.fields['password1']
        d = form.fields['password2']

    return render(response, 'register/register.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: you should try putting an `else` block after `if newUser`. Maybe your code is not going into `if` block. And submitting the same form twice with the same `csrf` token will fail token validation, which is expected.

Comment: Thanks. So what should I put in the ```else``` block then?